# How to rename label Shipping into delivery for order summary in Checkout page in magnento2.1.7?

Tags: magento2, checkout-page

I want to rename label (Shipping to delivery) only in order summary in Checkout page in magennto2.1.7 ?

Refer screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Check my answer. Its a working code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by following method:
Create a file with name **checkout_index_index.xml** under

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

and add the below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="summary" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="totals" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="shipping" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delivery</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Thats it! Above code will only execute in checkout. Need to flush the cache and test.

**Don't translate it through csv file as Shipping text might be used in different places in checkout, cart etc.**

Comment: Thanks friend, its working fine. great work:)

Comment: Welcome. Happy Coding! You can also do upvote for the answers which is working.

Comment: @SukumarGorai, is there a way to apply this to the shipping label only if the shipping country is Canada?

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit below file(en_US.csv) or create new file(en_US.csv) if not exist `app/design/frontend/Custom/default/i18n/en_US.csv` OR into `app/design/frontend/Custom/Magento_Checkout/i18n/en_US.csv`

like   `"Shipping","Delivery"`

run this commands after your change `php bin/magento cache:clean && php bin/magento cache:flush`

Comment: Hi, does it change only for Order summary in checkout page.

Comment: change into app/design/frontend/Custom/Magento_Checkout/i18n/en_US.csv file for only checkout